# ASP.NET MVC 3 XML Serialization: Serialize dash in element name from object property name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

[Trulia's Dev Guide](http://static.trulia-cdn.com/resources/TruliaDevGuide.pdf) uses dashes in their element names.  Assuming I create an object with similar names but with an underscore instead of a dash, would I need to create a custom XML serializer using [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx3wa6ka.aspx) to swap out the underscores with dashes or is there an easier way to do this?  (something like `.WriteElementString("street-address", myObject.street_address);`

Sample XML:

```
<location>
    <street-address>1234 Lane</street-address>
    <city-name>Midway</city-name>
    <state-code>GA</state-code>
    <zipcode>31320</zipcode>
    <display-address>true</display-address>
</location>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use attributes when serializing POCOs and deserializing XML, like the following:

```
[XmlElement("street-address")]
public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

[XmlElement("city-name")]
public string CityName { get; set; }
```