# C# a way to quote illegal characters in a variable name?

Tags: c#-4.0

Any way to get a dash as part of a property name in C#?

In SQL, it's `[some-thing]`.
In JavaScript, it's `myObject["some-thing"]`

I ask as a desperate attempt to avoid writing a custom XML serializer which uses dashes in the element names ([not by choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11219908/84424).)

Comment: Do you serialize the XML-Data to classes/objects using the XMLSerializer. Then you can use the XmlElementAttribute on properties to specify which tag maps to property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but based on your previous question if your problem is serializing / deserializing XML then you can use attributes, like the following:

```
[XmlElement("some-long-property")]
public string SomeLongProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you where asking, but you can use unicode in your variable.

You can also replace dash '-' with some other char, on the way in, and then back on the way out of your C# code.

```
"some-thing".Replace("-","_")
```